How to compute and interpret a multilevel variance inflation factor in R?
I am running some multilevel (mixed effect) models in R with two levels: three assessment timepoints (Level 1) clustered within individuals (Level 2). I would like to check multicollinearity between the predictors in my models. Here is an example model with anxiety (main predictor) and depression (covariate) predicting worry, with anxiety both person-mean-centered at each timepoint (Level 1) and also averaged over timepoints for each person (Level 2).
lmer(worry ~ anxiety_person_centered + anxiety_person_mean_centered + depression + (1|participant)

This 10-year old question was the only related question on Cross Validated, which links to this 13-year-old blog post, which offers some code in a git repository to calculate a multilevel variance inflation factor, copied below. The fit argument is the lmer model to be tested.
vif.mer <- function (fit) {
## adapted from rms::vif

v <- vcov(fit)
nam <- names(fixef(fit))

## exclude intercepts
ns <- sum(1 * (nam == "Intercept" | nam == "(Intercept)"))
if (ns > 0) {
    v <- v[-(1:ns), -(1:ns), drop = FALSE]
    nam <- nam[-(1:ns)]
}

d <- diag(v)^0.5
v <- diag(solve(v/(d %o% d)))
names(v) <- nam
v}

I've tried this code and it gives me a number for each predictor, but I don't understand how it's obtaining those numbers. For publication reasons, I need to be able to cite a published empirical article (not a blog post) that calculating multilevel VIFs is a thing and that this code does what it's supposed to do. I can't cite Patrick Carl Clark Jr's unpublished dissertation, and I'm having a hard time understanding Yu and colleagues (2015) - I don't know what "condition number kappas" are.
Could you explain to me, as if I am a smart high school student, what the above code for multilevel VIFs is doing, and provide a citation for this method if you have one to help me with interpretation?
